# 1 to 2 matching in two dataframes with different sizes in Python/R

Tags: python, r, dataframe, nested, matching

please help me with this problem I've been struggling all day lol, solution in either Python or R is fine! **Please help I'm really stuck!!!**

I have two dataframes - df1 has 44 rows, df2 has 100 rows, they both have these columns:
**ID, status (0,1), Age, Gender, Race, Ethnicity, Height, Weight**

for each row in df1, I need to find an **age** match in df2:

1. it can be exact age match, but the criteria should be used is - **df2[age]-5 <= df1[age]<= df2[age]+5**
2. I need a list/dictionary to store which are the age matches for df1, and their IDs
3. Then I need to randomly select 2 IDs from df2 as the final match for df1 age
4. **I also need to make sure the 2 df2 matches shares the same gender and race as df1**

**I have tried R and Python, and both stuck on the nested loops part.
I'm not sure how to loop through each record both df1 and df2, compare df1 age with df2 age-5 and df2 age+5, and store the matches**

Here are the sample data format for df1 and df2:
| ID       | sex            |  age   |  race |
| -------- | -------------- |--------|-------|
| 284336   | female         |  42.8  |  2    |
| 294123   | male           |  48.5  |  1    |

**Here is what I've attempted in R:**

```
id_match <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(gwi_case)){
  age <- gwi_case$age[i]
  gender <- gwi_case$gender[i]
  ethnicity <- gwi_case$hispanic_non[i]
  race <- gwi_case$race[i]
  
  x <- which(gwi_control$gender==gender & gwi_control$age>=age-5 & gwi_control$age<=age+5 & gwi_control$hispanic_non==ethnicity & gwi_control$race==race)
  
  y <- sample(x, min(2, length(x)))
  
  id_match <- c(id_match, y)
}

id_match <- id_match[!duplicated(id_match)]
length(id_match)
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt in either language?

Comment: Do not share images. Share the data

Comment: In R this is called non-equi join. Search for that.and you will find a way to solve your peoblem

Comment: @onyambu I have done some research, unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for here

Comment: @C.Nivs see code above, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks this:

- for each row in `df1`, find an age match in `df2` such that `df2[age] - 5 <= df1[age] <= df2[age] + 5`
- create a list/dictionary to hold age matches and IDs for df1
- randomly select 2 IDs from df2 as the final match for df1 age

Here is some Python code that:

- uses the criteria to populate list of lists `ageMatches` with a list of unique `df2` ages matching each unique `df1` age
- calls `DataFrame.query()` on `df2` for each age in `df1` to populate `idMatches` with a list of `df2` IDs with age matching each unique `df1` age
- populates `age1ToID2` with unique `df1` age keys and with values that are lists of 2 (or fewer if available number < 2) randomly selected `df2` IDs of matching age
- adds a column to `df1` containing the pair of selected `df2` IDs corresponding to each row's age (i.e., the values in `age1ToID2`)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(101,145)), 'Age':[v % 11 + 21 for v in range(44)], 'Height':[67]*44})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(1,101)), 'Age':[v % 10 + 14 for v in range(50)] + [v % 20 + 25 for v in range(0,100,2)], 'Height':[67]*100})

ages1 = np.sort(df1['Age'].unique())
ages2 = np.sort(df2['Age'].unique())
ageMatches = [[] for _ in ages1]
j1, j2 = 0, 0
for i, age1 in enumerate(ages1):
    while j1 < len(ages2) and ages2[j1] < age1 - 5:
        j1 += 1
    if j2 <= j1:
        j2 = j1 + 1
    while j2 < len(ages2) and ages2[j2] <= age1 + 5:
        j2 += 1
    ageMatches[i] += list(ages2[j1:j2])
idMatches = [df2.query('Age in @m')['ID'].to_list() for i, m in enumerate(ageMatches)]

# select random pair of df2 IDs for each unique df1 age and put them into a new df1 column
from random import sample
age1ToID2 = {ages1[i]:m if len(m) < 2 else sample(m, 2) for i, m in enumerate(idMatches)}
df1['df2_matches'] = df1['Age'].apply(lambda x: age1ToID2[x])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     ID  Age  Height df2_matches
0   101   21      67    [24, 30]
1   102   22      67    [50, 72]
2   103   23      67    [10, 37]
3   104   24      67    [63, 83]
4   105   25      67    [83, 49]
5   106   26      67    [20, 52]
6   107   27      67    [49, 84]
7   108   28      67    [54, 55]
8   109   29      67    [91, 55]
9   110   30      67    [65, 51]
10  111   31      67    [75, 72]
11  112   21      67    [24, 30]
...
42  143   30      67    [65, 51]
43  144   31      67    [75, 72]
```

This hopefully provides the result and intermediate collections that OP is asking for, or something close enough to get to the desired result.

Alternatively, to have the random selection be different for each row in `df1`, we can do this:

```py
# select random pair of df2 IDs for each df1 row and put them into a new df1 column
from random import sample
age1ToID2 = {ages1[i]:m for i, m in enumerate(idMatches)}
def foo(x):
    m = age1ToID2[x]
    return m if len(m) < 2 else sample(m, 2)
df1['df2_matches'] = df1['Age'].apply(foo)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     ID  Age  Height df2_matches
0   101   21      67    [71, 38]
1   102   22      67     [71, 5]
2   103   23      67     [9, 38]
3   104   24      67    [49, 61]
4   105   25      67    [27, 93]
5   106   26      67    [40, 20]
6   107   27      67     [9, 19]
7   108   28      67    [53, 72]
8   109   29      67    [82, 53]
9   110   30      67    [74, 62]
10  111   31      67    [52, 62]
11  112   21      67    [71, 39]
...
42  143   30      67    [96, 66]
43  144   31      67    [63, 83]
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! This is exactly what I'm asking about!! How would you make sure the gender between df1 and the 2 selections in df2 are the same?

Comment: I also updated my question for your reference! @constantstranger

Comment: Glad to hear this was helpful in answering your original question. Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted"

Comment: Hi! I'd love to accept your answer, but I have one more question, please re-read my post, truly appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Jessica Leung You have changed your question significantly since the time that I answered it. I would be happy to take a look at your modified question if you post it as a new separate question linking to this one, but since I have already spent time helping with your original question which you indicated was exactly what you're asking about, I'd appreciate your accepting the answer (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/significantly-edit-existing-question-or-ask-a-new-question-after-answer-accepte) for context). This is entirely up to you, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do appreciate your time and effort very much!! Here's the link to my new question, and I will accept your answer now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037322/1-to-2-matching-in-two-dataframes-with-different-sizes-in-python-r-second-part

Answer (score 0):

not sure I fully understand the requirement but... in python you can use apply to the dataframe and a lambda function to perform some funky things

```
df1['age_matched_ids'] = df1.apply(lambda x: list(df2.loc[df2['Age'] >= x['Age'] - 5 & df2['Age'] <= x['Age'] + 5, 'ID']), axis=1)
```

this will store in column 'age_matched_ids' the list of IDs from df2 that fall in between Age +/- 5. You can do #2 and #3 from here.

Comment: Thank you! But it raises this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: use & instead of 'and'.... going to add my answer it should sort the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Just updated the question with my code above as well